# Make programs with required libraries

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

Suppose that we have a program that uses only some of the libraries of .NET Frameworks, for example the I/O program that read and write file, so this program does not use as many as libraries like NET libraries and etc. So, i wanna make a program that include ONLY the libraries that is required to run! Not all of .NET Frameworks, can i do sth like this ? If yes, please explain your idea.

Thanks for your attention :)

Answer (score 3):

Your program does not "include" the required libraries. They are loaded as required, so you don't need to worry about your program loading libraries it does not actually use.

If your actual worry is that your users need to install the complete .NET framework, you could have a look at the [.NET Framework Client Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx). That is a smaller installer and does not install the complete framework.

Comment: I wanna create a program that `include` required libraries! I don't want to install .NET Framework!

Answer (score 1):

When you install the .net framework it includes all the required libraries. .net libraries that you reference in your program are not included with it when you distribute it.

Answer (score 0):

Your application does not include the entire .NET Framework.  This is why users are required to install the .NET Framework before they c an run your application.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking if you can write a program that will run on a machine without the .Net framework installed? And then to only include the dll files that are needed for that specific application.

I think that the .Net framework must be installed on the machine as the .exe you compile using the CLR's compiler automatically checks that the framework is installed when you execute it.

Even the smallest .exe you create will be in a PE32 format, and the ones emitted by csc.exe contain a sort of bootstrap at the top that kicks off the CLR's Just in Time compilation etc.

So you need to have the framework installed for this functionality regardless of what libraries you call.

This is as I understand it.

For what you want to do you probably need to write non-managed or unsafe code using c++ and calling Win32 DLL's directly.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [setup project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx3b589t.aspx) that installs the required .NET Framework when they install your application.